# Elasticsearch: Full match of query value from beginning to end of field

Tags: elasticsearch, pattern-matching, full-text-search

I have problem with full match querying of field value. **title** and **gender** - fields of indexed docs

```
query: {
  query_string: {
    query: "box AND gender:\"women\"",
    default_field: "title"
  }
}
```

I use double quotes to match full query for **gender**. But if there is **gender** "men,women" with **title** 'box' it also will be in results. I know, that elasticsearch does not support regexp characters ^ and $ for beginning and end of the string, so I couldn't make `/^women$/`.

What do I need to do if I want docs matching only 'women' **gender**, not 'men,women' ?

Comment: Can you please share your mapping and a minimal document to reproduce your use case ? Also, do you need to use a query_string ? Are you open for bool queries ?

Comment: I will try to share information in some time. I tried bool->must too, bur the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [apt-get_install_skill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11486670/apt-get-install-skill). Keyword did the work, but with some addings.

Summary this is solution:

```
query: {
    bool: {
      must: {
        query_string: {
          query: "box",
          default_field: "title"
        }
      },
      filter: {
        bool: {
          should: [
            {term: {"gender.keyword": "women"}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

I need should as array for searching multiple genders if I will need it. For example, some docs have unisex gender, such as 'women,men'
Example with multiple genders:

```
query: {
    bool: {
      must: {
        query_string: {
          query: "box",
          default_field: "title"
        }
      },
      filter: {
        bool: {
          should: [
            {term: {"gender.keyword": "women"}},
            {term: {"gender.keyword": "kids"}} 
            #summary it may be gender 'girls'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Q:

> What do I need to do if I want docs matching only 'women' gender, not 'men,women' ?

For exact searches you should use a terms query rather than a fulltext-search query like the query_string. So to get all documents that matches exactly gender == women you should do it like so:

```
GET your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "gender.keyword": {
              "value": "women"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please be aware that this query assumes that the gender-field is also mapped as a keyword.

To complete the query you would add another must-clause to get all documents that have *box* in the title field *women* as the value of the gender-field.

```
GET your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "gender.keyword": {
              "value": "women"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "box"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Keyword did the work, but with some addings.
Look for the next solution

Comment: I have posted working solution for my ptoblem https://stackoverflow.com/a/59476375/7065800